# Django notify when model changes

Tags: django

I have a big legacy Django1.11 project and I want to make some changes on a table. I needed to be notified (notification is not a big deal here and suppose i just want to print "hello world" in case of happening) when every change on this table happens (every insert or or update in rows) and I can not be sure I can find all of this changes in code because it is so big.

I searched and I figured out if I override `save` method in Model I will be notified in some cases and still i will be missing some changes in rows. For example when `Model.objects.filter().update()` I will be missing changes.

I wanted to know Is there a way that I can be sure that I will catch every happens in rows of Model table?

Comment: You need to take a look at [Django Model Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#module-django.db.models.signals)

Comment: @ChihebNexus: the signals are not triggered by the `.update(..)` (in bulk). I don't think it is entirely possible no. THere are ways to circumvent a lot of logic.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You're right. In this case the possibility i can think of is to do the bulk update then manually trigger the signals ... But it's a lot of logic of something that may have a better solution.

Comment: Have you thought about overriding and extending the save method?

Comment: @hendrikschneider yeah, but as I mentioned when we use .update() I will be missing some changes.